# Baire Category Theorem with $G_{\delta}$

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

If we have a subset $Y$ of a complete metric space $X$ such that $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$, then how would I go to show that $Y$ satisfies the Baire category theorem?

I am trying to get there by showing that any meagre subset $Z \subseteq Y$ has $int(Z)=\emptyset$ but do not know how to use the fact that $X$ is complete in my proof... Any help or ideas? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show that $Y$ is completely metrizable, therefore a Baire space.

Comment: We have never seen this notion in our course... Would you know how to show this using empty interior of meagre sets?

Comment: Look at my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130245/g-delta-sets-in-locally-compact-hausdorff-or-complete-metric-space-are-bair/1133343#1133343